# Splitting monthly values into daily values with python

Tags: python, dataframe, smoothing, curve

I have two dataframes. dataframe1 has columns 'id' and 'jan', 'feb', 'mar', ..., 'nov', 'dec' (which are monthly sale predictions).

dataframe1:
[image]
dataframe2 has two columns: 'id' and 'date' (%d-%m-%Y).

I joined dataframe1 in dataframe2 by 'id' and generated a column 'daily_predictions'.

(joined)dataframe2:
[image]

Problem: I want to break down such monthly predictions into daily predictions. However, I do not want to simply divide the month prediction by the number of days in the month, as I am looking for a distribution of values that links the daily predictions between months in a smoother way (not in a step-scaled fashion). The month average of such daily values should approximate (or be on) the month prediction.

For example, in the row where id=1 and date=03/01/2022, the only value I would use to fill 'daily_predictions' is that from 'january' (100), because the date (03/01/2022) is in January (column 'july' and the others won't be used). Now, the point is how could I split 100 between the days in January.

Which (python/numpy/etc) function could I reference to do that? Is it possible to define a function that would do that or have I no choice but to divide the month prediction by the number of days in the month? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the joined data is telling us, or how you expect to derive anything from it. What does, for example, the data point at `03/01/2022` x `july` tell me? That I predict there will be 190 orders placed in July in January? In July, we predicted that there would be 190 orders for item ID 1 placed on 3rd January? In other words, how would you derive the `daily predictions` column by hand at a given step?

Comment: Great question @G.Anderson. In that row (id=1, date=03/01/2022), the only value that I would use to fill 'daily_predictions' is that from 'january' (100), because the date (03/01/2022) is in January (column 'july' and the others won't be used). Likewise, in the row where id=1 and date=20/10/2022 I would use the value from column 'october' (130) to fill 'daily_predictions'. Now, the point is how could I split 100 between the days in January and 130 between the days in October. I am going to edit the main question on this point.

Comment: Given that clarification, a) it doesn't seem like there's a need to join these in the first place as it implies relationships within the data that aren't there and b) you would have to decide how you would want the data distributed across the month. There are a number of [distributions available through scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) that you could use to "spread" the data across the month (the uniform distribution being equivalent to just using the mean)